# Cannot find reference to Python package (plt.cm.py)

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, scikit-learn, pycharm

I have a small issue with running code from a tutorial that isn't working as it should. It's not a syntax problem for sure. I'm working with scikit-learn and matplotlib, and I'm getting a warning message in my IDE "Cannot find reference 'gray_r' in 'cm.py'..." All my packages are installed properly (via pip) and have worked for sample programs except this.

Any advice?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets        
from sklearn import svm             

digits = datasets.load_digits()     

print(digits.data)
print(digits.target)
print(digits.images[0])

clf = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, C=100)

print(len(digits.data))

x, y = digits.data[:-1], digits.target[:-1] 
clf.fit(x,y)

print('Prediction:', clf.predict(digits.data[-1])

plt.imshow(digits.images[-1], cmap=plt.cm.gray_r, interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for starters your missing a closing parenthesis on your last print statement: `print('Prediction:', clf.predict(digits.data[-1]))` Other than that, this code runs on my computer with only a deprecation warning. What does the traceback say?

Comment: I'm an idiot - just fixed it and all's good! I'm a bit rusty and just realized I should really get back into the habit of debugging and not just glancing over. Thanks again!